# Почему this не является ссылкой на родительский объект?

Tags: javascript

Почему `this` в первом примере не является ссылкой на родительский объект?

```
var obj = {
    some: this
};
console.log(obj.some); // (1) получаем window, хотя вызываем от obj



var ObjConstructor = function () {
    this.some = this;
};
obj = new ObjConstructor();
console.log(obj.some); // (2) получаем объект, созданный ObjConstructor'ом, как и ожидалось
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Потому, что в первом примере `this` в момент присваивания значения `some`, указывает на `window` т.к. происходит это вне конструктора (или функции).

Во втором случае, при вызове функции коструктора `this` указывает на новый созданный объект.

Чтобы работал первый пример, нужно сделать так:

```
var obj = {
    some: function() { return this; }
};
console.log(obj.some());
```

Comment: чтобы не указывать скобочки,  можно сделать этот метод свойством `var obj = {
    get some() { return this; }
};
console.log(obj.some);`

Answer (score -1):

```js
console.log(obj) // undefined
var obj = {
 "test": console.log(obj), /*  хоть мы и объявили obj но пока не
 завершили присвоение всех свойств модели получаем undefined */
 "test_1": console.log(this), /* получаем window так как присвоения 
свойств происходит в контексте глобального объекта, после чего this уже 
 имеет раскрытый контекст и только обратную контекстной силу.*/
    "some": this /* происходит  не  объявления, а присвоение расширения в
 ключе some*/
};
console.log(obj.some); // (1) получаем window, хотя вызываем от obj
console.log(obj.test_1) /* получаем undefined, хотя вызываем console.log(this). Так как методы были вызваны в момент присвоения  и они уже не имеют функциональности*/ 


var ObjConstructor = function () {
    this.some = this;
};
var obj_1 = new ObjConstructor();
console.log(obj_1 .some); // (2) получаем объект, созданный ObjConstructor'ом, как и ожидалось

ObjConstructor.call(obj) /* присвоил набор свойств обекту obj от
конструктора  ObjConstructor */

console.log(obj.some) /* теперь, расширение ключа some, this  указывает
 на контекст объекта так как мы его переписали и в момент присвоения this
 ссылался на контекст вызова который был задан методом call*/
```